# CSS full width of absolute element

Tags: html, css

I have a table with a drop-down filter content field. Example below. I want the 
 dropdown content to have exactly the same width as the table. How can I do this? If I put `width:100%` inside the `.dropdown-content` class, the width is too big.

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 5px 8px 16px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <div *ngIf="filtering" class="dropdown">
    <span></span>
    <div class="dropdown-content" flex layout="row" layout-wrap>
      <mat-form-field class="searchFields" flex>
        <input name="test" flex type="number" matInput [(ngModel)]="test" placeholder="test">
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>
  <tr>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: A `div` within a `table` is semantically incorrect, and in fact is causing the div to be rendered before the table as a sibling - check your browser's dev tools.

Comment: Soreak, you've used an `=` sign rather than a `:` colon in your inline table width style. it should be `<table style="width:100%">`

Comment: @chazsolo Yeah, that's why I am searching for a solution..

Comment: @Matt Changed it to 'width:100%'

Comment: _“Yeah, that's why I am searching for a solution”_ - well then either put the filter before the table to begin with, or put it _properly_ into the table, by placing it inside a table row and cell. (Might even make sense to add it into a thead, and the actual data inside a tbody.)

Comment: It's just a simple representation for a problem I had in my application where the table isn't even used..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is bad practice to used `div` with in `table`. and the `table` should style like this `<table style="width:100%">`

For your question, It because you add padding in `dropdown-content`, so the total width is: 100% + 32px(padding left & right), So
Add  `box-sizing:border-box` (it includes the content, padding and border within the width) in `dropdown-content`, So it was fixed issue with padding and 100% width.

Here is [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp) for more clarification:

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 5px 8px 16px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: -15px;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Add this*/
  width: 100%; /* Add this*/
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <div *ngIf="filtering" class="dropdown">
    <span></span>
    <div class="dropdown-content" flex layout="row" layout-wrap>
      <mat-form-field class="searchFields" flex>
        <input name="test" flex type="number" matInput [(ngModel)]="test" placeholder="test">
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>
  <tr>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

A div within a table is incorrect but still you can use it within table... and the table style should be `<table style="width:100%">`... use `box-sizing: border-box` (it includes the content, padding and border within the width) to fix the 100% with padding issue...

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 5px 8px 16px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: -15px;
  width:100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <div *ngIf="filtering" class="dropdown">
    <span></span>
    <div class="dropdown-content" flex layout="row" layout-wrap>
      <mat-form-field class="searchFields" flex>
        <input name="test" flex type="number" matInput [(ngModel)]="test" placeholder="test">
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>
  <tr>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Auto Width Content

[image]

### This is How I did it

In the below code, I added a div called `content` and gave it a width of `auto`. I then made your `dropdown` a `100% - 32px` for the `padding` using the CSS `calc` function.

> `width: calc(100% - 32px)`;

However, using `box-sizing: border-box;` with `width: 100%;` is probally better.

I also added some background colour and made the drop down slightly transparent so you could see it better.

```css
    .content {
    display:inline-block;
    width:auto;
    background:#ddd;
    
    }
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: rgba(249, 249, 249, 0.79);
      box-shadow: 5px 8px 16px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      padding: 12px 16px;
      z-index: 1;
      margin-top: -15px;
      width: calc(100% - 32px);
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="content">
    <table style="width=100%">
      <div *ngIf="filtering" class="dropdown">
        <span></span>
        <div class="dropdown-content" flex layout="row" layout-wrap>
          <mat-form-field class="searchFields" flex>
            <input name="test" flex type="number" matInput [(ngModel)]="test" placeholder="test">
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
      </div>
      <tr>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```